# Share microservices between different projects

Tags: database, design-patterns, microservices

I want to make a microservice project including some microservices like: page, order, products and etc.
I have two questions about that:

1. I want to know if it is a good idea to reuse the same microservice in different projects and store multiple websites data in one microservice and retrieve corresponding data by the project token?

   For example we have website A and website B and share their data in the same microservice database and products microservice holds website A and website B products.
2. If reusing microservice is a good idea, then problems may occur if maybe there are some slight changes between website A and website B products. Should I rewrite another microservice for website B or write a generic product microservice so it can handle different types of products?

Comment: The idea behind microservices is that you define a bounded context and the write a service on the top which owns the data and the operations.
Your problem boils down to defining the bounded context. If you define it well , you won't face issues like service specific changes , changing the core logic.

Comment: I think code reuse and generic components would lead you down the mini monolith path, which is an anti pattern... Write each components to address the correct business functionality even if it looks slimier, in the long run they will most likliy diverge based on changes to business requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first time you can write generic service that is used by two or more consumers, but it will bring you problems if business logic changes for one of the consumers.

My advice would be, if you think that system will not change frequently and does not grow much, make shared service, otherwise decoupling would be much better approach.